# Accessing a particular directory via HTTPS

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, https, lamp

I am trying to create a particular directory on my LAMP installation folder to be HTTPS enabled. I was reading about that and i found out it can be done in httpd.conf. However i do not have https.conf but apach2.conf

I also have two files :

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf
```

I tried creating a SSL certificate using the instructions at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-apache-on-arch-linux bust still not able to hit my URL via HTTPS though it works with HTTP.

For the above reference point i was not able to complete step 3.

Server Config:

LAMP stack installed over Ubuntu.

Comment: Could you include the config files?

Answer (score 0):

The file "sites-available/default-ssl.conf" can be used to set up a default HTTPS install, provided you put in your SSL certs etc - and assuming this directory is read by Apache - which it is by default on most installs which have this layout.

ie sites-available/default-ssl.conf negates the need to include conf/extra-httpd-ssl.conf (but there is nothing stopping you creating conf/xtra/httpd-ssl.conf and linking the file into your httpd.conf file if you so desire)